# post-recieve not invoked when pushing from GIT Bash on Windows

Tags: git, git-post-receive

Hey, 
I have a post-receive hook enabled on my remote repository, works fine when pushing tags\commit upstream from Linux Machine. ( although I have to sudo when pushing ) .
However - when pushing from Windows Git client, scripts is not invoked. 
Any Ideas ?

Thanks, 
Ran

Answer (score 1):

Are the scripts not invoked or you are not just seeing the output of the script on the Windows Git client? Anyway, I would recommend you to update the client if it is not latest.

Comment: So the scripts sends email every time a ref is being pushed to the repo..no emails when pushing from Win Machines, although the changes are reflected in the repo. I'm thinking may my repo is not set up correctly..it should be defined as public repo...for now it is just a bare repo

Answer (score 0):

Might be a ridiculous suggestion. But are you really sure that you push to the same repository? Check with git remote -v and compare origin (or whatever your remote repo is called)